# MailKit C# SmtpClient.Connect() to Office 365 generating exception: "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"

Tags: c#, office365, mailkit

I have a problem sending email via Office 365 SMTP and MailKit. The exception I get is:

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from
>   the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed
>   by the remote host.
>
> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was
>   forcibly closed by the remote host

https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit

Code:

```
var smtpClient = new SmtpClient();

smtpClient.Connect("smtp.office365.com", 587, true);
```

Microsoft Office 365 settings should be correct:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/POP-and-IMAP-settings-for-Outlook-Office-365-for-business-7fc677eb-2491-4cbc-8153-8e7113525f6c

The weird thing is that if I use the following everything works, even though Office 365 says SSL is required.

```
smtpClient.Connect("smtp.office365.com", 587, false);
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Got another error after posting this question which led me to the answer:

> Handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format

The solution is to connect to Office 365 like this instead:

```
smtpClient.Connect("smtp.office365.com", 587, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
```

Comment: Just commenting to confirm that this is the correct solution. SMTP really only uses SSL-wrapped connections on port 465. Port 2 and 587 use StartTLS if they use "SSL" at all. This is, unfortunately, not generally explained well in configuration guides.

Comment: This just saved me too. I made the mistake of reading the documentation :)

Comment: This solution does not work for me after deploying to Ubuntu server. Any ideas?